# RazorPay - Linking customer while creating subscription

Tags: reactjs, nest, razorpay

Okay, SO I am new to razorPay, but i think it is fairly simple. Though I am stuck with one issue here, which is linking customer to subscription. I don't know how it happens but it did create a customer the first time i ran the code, after that i tried and i don't know for some reason it is just creating the active subscription but no customer.

Here is the React Code:

```js
var options = {
    "key": "rzp_test_M0000000000",
    "subscription_id": id,
    "name": "Acme Corp.",
    "description": "Monthly Test Plan",
    "image": "/your_logo.png",
    "handler": function(response) {
      alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
      alert(response.razorpay_subscription_id);
      alert(response.razorpay_signature);
    },
    "prefill": {
      "name": "Gaurav Kumar",
      "email": "Gauv@xyz.com",
      "contact": "+917000000000"
    },
    "notes": {
      "note_key_1": "Tea. Earl Grey. Hot",
      "note_key_2": "Make it so."
    },
    "theme": {
      "color": "#F37254"
    }
  };
  const paymentObject = new window.Razorpay(options);
  paymentObject.open();
```

Can someone tell me what am i missing here!!